# Expand environment variable for My Documents

Tags: c#, .net, environment-variables, environment, special-folders

I know I can read environment variables like this:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

However, it would be really helpful to me if I could do something like this:

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%MyDocuments%\Foo");
```

Is there an environement variable that equals SpecialFolder.MyDocuments?

I also tried to do something like this, but this doesn't lead to the expected result:

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Foo");
```

This way I ended up with something like `@"C:\Users\<MyUser>\My Documents\Foo"` but I what I need is `@"\\someservername\users$\<MyUser>\My Documents\Foo"`.

**EDIT:** My Goal is NOT to hardcode either environment variable nor the part after that.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  What would the end result of the above be, if it worked how you expected?

Comment: OK what I'm trying to do is: I want to put the whole path in the config file and just expand it to whatever it points to. So it could easily changed from @"%appdata%\foo" to @"%appdatalocal%\bar" or similar. Not hardcoding either environment variable nor the part after that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No there is no environment variable for the `MyDocuments` special folder (the same is true for most members of the `SpecialFolder` enumeration).

Check out [this snippet](http://www.hqsnippets.net/snippet/9/expand-environment-variables-and-special-folders.html), it might be exactly what you are searching for.

It allows you to do something like that:

```
string fullPath = SpecialFolder.ExpandVariables(@"%MyDocuments%\Foo");
```

Note: SpecialFolder.ExpandVariables is a static method of a helper class introduced in the above snippet.

Comment: @HQSnippets that snippet is gone? In fact the whole domain seems gone? http://www.whois.net/whois/hqsnippets.net

Comment: Bummer. Not much left of it in the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://hqsnippets.net/*)

Answer (score 9):

> Is there an environment variable that equals `SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`?

Short answer: **No.**

Long answer:
Still no. You can type `"set"` into a Command Prompt to see all you current environment variables. I couldn't find any for my documents folder on my profile (tried on WinXP and Win7).

Also, expanding `"%USERPROFILE%\My Documents"` would be incorrect since the user's documents folder could be anywhere else (e.g., on my home PC I always change mine to `D:\Documents`).

If you *really* need to use environment variables, one solution might be to set the variable yourself:

```
// this environment variable is created for the current process only
string documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MYDOCUMENTS", documents);
```

Another solution might be to use a "fake" environment variable in the path and expand it yourself, something like:

```
string path = "%MYDOCUMENTS%\\Foo"; // read from config

// expand real env. vars
string expandedPath1 = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);

// expand our "fake" env. var
string documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string expandedPath2 = path.Replace("%MYDOCUMENTS%", documents);
```

Answer (score 3):

What exactly are you trying to do? Is there any reason why you can't just use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx)?

```
string docs = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string foo = Path.Combine(docs, "Foo");
```

Comment: I try not to hard code either the special folder nor the Foo part.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a good way to do this but instead of trying to do environment expansion to get the path why not use the `Path.Combine` API instead?

```
Path.Combine(
  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
  "Foo");
```

Comment: I try to avoid hard coding any part of the path.

Comment: @wkada well when you hard code them into the question and don't provide context it makes it hard to answer the question.

Comment: Well I updated / commented my question one minute after submiting. Didn't expect an answer immediately :( My bad...

Answer (score 1):

You can expand environment variables using then `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` method.  Given your comment, I would suggest breaking your path up into 2 separate config settings to make expanding it easier:

```
string variablePath = "%appdata%".Trim('%'); //read from some config setting
string appdataPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(variablePath);
string subdir = "foo";  //some other config setting
string myDir = Path.Combine(appdataPath, subdir);
```

Comment: No, this does not solve my problem. It's no problem to do something like that: Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%appdata%\Foo"); But I don't know the environment variable that stands for the my documents folder (if it exists at all).

Comment: Then why not just map it yourself saying if you find the string %mydocuments% in the path after normal expansion (match it with a regex for casing), then change it to Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments?

Comment: It would be great if I could take in any path from the config file, expand it and use it without any further processing. And if it should be universal I had to handle every Environment.SpecialFolder enum member that doesn't have it's environment variable like that (or a subset of them that is relevant). Of course there are other options. But if this worked it would be brilliant ;-)

Comment: It would be nice, but that's when we developers have to get creative and create an elegant solution that's transparent to the application administrators...

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after :) Thus my question.

Answer (score 1):

No it does not exist. The easiest way to check is to run "set" from command line and see yourself.

```
Start-> run -> cmd
set
set |findstr /i documents
```