# How to resolve environment variables programatically in C# without using Environment Enum?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, environment-variables, class-library

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expand environment variable for My Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726818/expand-environment-variable-for-my-documents)

We often use %% delimited environment variables in Command prompt in Windows Xp, 7, Vista, Server 2003-2008R2 and possibly in future windows versions. Examples are:

```
%windir%
%systemroot%
%temp%
```

I need to be able to programatically resolve these environment variables using C#.

Please do not suggest `Environmen.SpecialFolder` , because i am getting values from a webservice in the above formats and i need to able to programmatically resolve them and determine physical location of these paths on server. My scenario is a class libarary project and i may **NOT** require/be able to use `Server.MapPath`

I am looking for a generic method builtin or custom that can help me resolve all environment variables pro grammatically and calculate local physical paths from these variables just Command Prompt or Windows Explorer or Run Command does !

I have seen questions similar to these on StackOverFlow but couldn't find any marked answers. Please note that `Environment.Xxxxx Enum` doesnt cater for the scenario i am working through.

Any help is appreciated. I am using .NET 4.0 Complete Framework Profile with C#.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable.aspx

Comment: Have you tried [ExpandEnvironmentVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

<s>You can use [`System.IO.Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx). For example:</s>

```
var resolvedPath = Path.GetFullPath("%WINDIR%");
```

Or if you just want to expand variables in a string, use [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx):

```
var expanded = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
    "This is my %WINDIR% in %SYSTEMROOT%, and temp is %TEMP%")
```

Comment: I updated the answer. Original answer had `Path.GetFullPath("%WINDIR%")`. This returns `"C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Local\Temp\%WINDIR%"` on my system (.NET 4). Also, documentation doesn't mention it expanding environment variables.

Comment: @johv is correct. The first part of this answer is just plain wrong. `Path.GetFullPath` *does not* expand environment variables. Tested on .NET 4.5 Win 7 64 bit.

Comment: Will that work on Linux too in .Net Core?

Answer (score 12):

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%windir%\SomeFolder")
```