# Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") strange behavior

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, windows-xp, environment-variables

The line is

```
if (!val.Contains(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir")))
```

Which seems to work just fine with a Windows 7(64-bit) system and will detect whether the string I'm looking at contains any version of c:\windows with any capitalization. But under XP, the same code does not seem to detect the changes in case. I have all the results printing to the console for debugging and some c:\WINDOWS are getting through, but when I execute

```
echo %windir%
```

in the Command window, I get C:\WINDOWS. Is there a way to rewrite my test so that it doesn't break compatibility with Win7 but will catch these differences with XP?

Thanks

Comment: `Contains()` is always case-sensitive.

Comment: Answer already available at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275338/how-to-resolve-environment-variables-programatically-in-c-sharp-without-using-en

Answer (score 9):

I'd recommend using this instead to get the windows folder:

```
var windowsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows)
```

And you can do this for case-insensitive comparison:

```
if (val.IndexOf(windowsPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) < 0)
```